# list_display - boolean icons for methods

Tags: django, django-admin

When defining the list_display array for a `ModelAdmin` class, if a `BooleanField` or `NullBooleanField` is given the UI will use nice looking icons instead of True/False text in the column. If a method that returns a boolean is given, however, it simply prints out True/False.

Is there a way to make it use the pretty icons for a boolean method?

Answer (score 283, accepted):

This is documented, although it's a bit hard to find - go a couple of screens down from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), and you'll find this:

> If the string given is a method of the model, ModelAdmin or a callable that returns True or False Django will display a pretty "on" or "off" icon if you give the method a `boolean` attribute whose value is `True`.

and the example given is:

```
def born_in_fifties(self):
    return self.birthday.strftime('%Y')[:3] == '195'
born_in_fifties.boolean = True
```

Comment: Any idea how to do it when you use the @property decorator?: "AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'boolean'"

Comment: @Kye http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842095/how-to-display-a-boolean-property-in-the-django-admin

Comment: Do not forget that this only works if the method is not static!

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to @daniel-roseman (rtfm)
Since Django 3.2 [there is a decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.display) `@admin.display(boolean=True)`:

> If the string (in `list_display`) given is a method of the model,
> `ModelAdmin` or a callable that returns `True`, `False`, or `None`, Django
> will display a pretty “yes”, “no”, or “unknown” icon if you wrap the
> method with the `display()` decorator passing the `boolean` argument with
> the value set to `True`:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    birthday = models.DateField()

    @admin.display(boolean=True)
    def born_in_fifties(self):
        return 1950 <= self.birthday.year < 1960
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work for me (Django 3.1.10)

```
class MyAdmin(MyModel):
    list_display = ("field_as_boolean", )
    
    def field_as_boolean(self, obj):
        return True if obj.field else False
    field_as_boolean.boolean = True
    field_as_boolean.short_description = "field_name"
```