# How to display a boolean property in the django admin

Tags: django

As we all know, displaying a *method* return value as boolean in the Django admin is easily done by setting the `boolean` attribute:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def is_something(self):
        if self.something == 'something':
            return True
        return False
    is_something.boolean = True
```

How can you achieve the same effect for a property, like in the following case?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    @property
    def is_something(self):
        if self.something == 'something':
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Waiting for better solutions to come up, I've solved it in the following way:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def _is_something(self):
        if self.something == 'something':
            return True
        return False
    _is_something.boolean = True
    is_something = property(_is_something)
```

I'll then reference the `_is_something` method in the `ModelAdmin` subclass:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['_is_something']
```

And the `is_something` property otherwise:

```
if my_model_instance.is_something:
    print("I'm something")
```

Comment: Using django-jet I ran into this issue and it was related to CSS not showing the icon depending on the theme https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet/issues/300

Answer (score 42):

this is the simplest way I found, directly in the ModelAdmin:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def is_something(self, instance):
        return instance.something == "something"
    is_something.boolean = True
    is_something.short_description = u"Is something"

    list_display = ['is_something']
```

Comment: Works for me, but I need to change `list_display = ['is_something']` to `list_display = ['_is_something']` and add `@property` to my model function to work.

Comment: And take care if you call this method before with `is_something()` now you need to call it without parentesis `is_something`

Comment: Far better solution since it does not require to pollute your model with admin related stuff.

Answer (score 18):

You need to create a `shadowing` function to the property in the model. What I mean is that you will need to recreate a function in the ModelAdmin class with the same name as the property defined in the main Model.

Example:

```
# Model
class Product(models.Model):

    @property  # you can omit this decorator if you will access this property as a method of the model instance
    def in_stock(self):
        # boolean check return
        return self.quantity > 0
```

...

```
# Django-modeladmin
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('in_stock', ...)
    def in_stock(self, instance):
        return instance.in_stock

    in_stock.boolean = True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a decorator like this

```
from six.moves import reduce

def list_property(field_name, **kwargs):
    def _from_property(obj):
        rv = reduce(getattr, field_name.split("."), obj)
        return rv() if callable(rv) else rv

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(_from_property, key, value)
    return _from_property
```

here are your model and admin definitions:

```
# model

class MyModel(models.Model):
    @property
    def is_something(self):
        if self.something == 'something':
            return True
        return False


# admin

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [list_property("is_something", boolean=True)]
```

for readonly fields in modeladmin you can use this decorator instead:

```
def field_property(field_name, **kwargs):
    def _from_property(admin, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return None
        rv = reduce(getattr, field_name.split("."), obj)
        return rv() if callable(rv) else rv

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(_from_property, key, value)
    return _from_property

# admin
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ["is_something"]

    is_something = field_property("is_something", boolean=True)
```

Comment: Minor improvement to have a single decorator for both cases: `def _from_property(admin_or_obj, obj=None): if not isinstance(admin_or_obj, admin.ModelAdmin): obj = admin_or_obj`

Answer (score -1):

If you define `is_something` as a property, it will be an immutable object, instead of a function, but that object contains a reference to the decorated getter in the `fget` attribute. I think that the Django admin interface use the getter of that property, thus this may works

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    @property
    def is_something(self):
        if self.something == 'something':
            return True
        return False
    is_something.fget.boolean = True
```

Comment: What did you put in list_display? It may work if you put is_something.fget (but I think this is pretty close to your solution)

Comment: Doesn't work either, Django explicitly disallows that. I'll mark my solution as accepted then, thank you anyways ;)