# How can I add a nullable or boolean field to ManyToManyField Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to add a boolean field which is 'is_featured' column in a pivot table of Portfolio.

I want to add images gallery with multiple images but among them there will be a featured image or first one will be featured if there is more than one images is featured.

**I have found that by 'through' is possible only if a reference table exist but that does not solve my problem when i want to a extra static column.**
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
from category.models import Category
from imageGallery.models import ImageGallery
from tag.models import Tag


class Portfolio(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=191)
    description = HTMLField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True) 

    gallery = models.ManyToManyField(ImageGallery, blank=True) # > Here I want to add another column 'is_feature' !!!!

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Generally gallery will create a pivot table portfolio_portfolio_imageGallery where, 
1. I want add another column 'is_feature' that could be nullable, or a boolean 
2. and is it possible to have a checkbox, or text field for 'is_featured' column when i choose an image from admin

table detail,
id 
portfolio_id 
imageGallery_id 
is_feature <- **is extra column I want to add. Any help will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: For the `tag` or the `gallery`? The question text and code seem to contradict each other.

Comment: my mistake. Its corrected already. Its for gallery. Like I want to add another column 'is_featured'

Comment: **1.** You could use [BooleanField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) and set `null=True` like so `is_featured = models.BooleanField(null=True)`. This is dependent on the version of Django you are using.

Comment: **2.** I think you are looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227023/list-display-boolean-icons-for-methods)

Comment: @EronV I am using latest version if Django. It will be better for me if you just explain with proper code and instruction. It will be greatly appreciated.